# Why does it output differently when printing and exporting into .csv file?

Tags: python, csv

When I run this command in script 1 `print(test.dataScraper(merchantID, productID))` it prints multiple values.

While when I export it to .csv

```
df = pd.DataFrame(script2.dataScraper(merchantID, productID))
df.to_csv("plsWork.csv")
```

it only prints the last value and not all of them.

**SCRIPT 1**

```
import script2

with open('productID.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:

        merchantID = (line[2])
        productID = (line[4])

        if len(productID) == 0:
            break

        df = pd.DataFrame(script2.dataScraper(merchantID, productID))
        df.to_csv("plsWork.csv")

        #print(test.dataScraper(merchantID, productID))
```

**SCRIPT 2**

```
def dataScraper(merchantID, productID):

    ## Product Information
        data_dict['Product ID'] = data['data']['id']
        data_dict['Product Name'] = data['data']['name']
        data_dict['Product Size'] = bottleSize
        data_dict['Product Option ID'] = optionID
        data_dict['Quantity In Stock'] = availableQuantity

        master_list.append(data_dict)

        if size == 0:
            break

    return(master_list)
```

Comment: Why are you using pandas here at all? It makes no sense... Just use the csv module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to parse your code, because it is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), however you have some obvious issues:

- `dataScraper` takes two variables, and uses neither of them. Instead, you're relying on some variables not local to the function. This is bad practice.
- `dataScraper` is continuously overwriting a non-local variable `data_dict`.
- `dataScraper` returns *either* a `None` value or the now-modified array.
- But your main problem is probably that you are writing to `to_csv` for each loop of your `for line in csv_reader` stanza. If your `master_list` is getting re-created on each loop then it will only ever have the last value you process in it, because the `to_csv` function is not appending, it's overwriting.

To at least isolate your problems, you should make your functions utilize only local variables. Something like:

```
def process_file(file_to_read: str, output_file: str) -> None:
    with open(file_to_read, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(csv_reader)  # Skip column headers
       
        processed_dicts = [ scrape_data(line[2], line[4]) for line in csv_reader ]
        pprint(processed_dict)  # Just to prove to ourselves it's correct, comment out for prod
        df = pd.DataFrame(processed_dicts)
        df.t0_csv(output_file)

def scrape_data(merchant_id, product_id) -> dict:
    data = ...?  # Either this should be passed in as a param or fetched from somewhere.
    processed_dict = {
        'Product Id': data['data']['id'],
        ... # all your other things
    }
    return processed_dict
```

As you can see, there is a big hole where `data` is, but this structure should keep your problems constrained. Remember: global variables are not your friend!

(Also, as an aside, you should really use idiomatic Python snake-case for your variable names, aka `scrape_data` not `scrapeData`.)